# (error while creating beans ) - org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name studentRepository

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to create a basic web service using JPA. But beans are not being initialised. can anyone help me on this ?

The error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.Spring.DataJPA.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration:
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.Spring.Data.Student
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
```

**Student.java**

```
package com.Spring.Data;

import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.InjectionClassLoader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Entity
public class Student {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
   private String firstName;

   public Long getId() {
     return id;
   }

   private String lastName;
   private int age;
   private Address address;

   public Student(){

   }

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int age, Address address) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFullName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
            "fullName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            ", address=" + address +
            '}';
}
}
```

**Address.java**

```
public class Address {
    private String houseNo;
    private String city;
    private String pincode;
    private String landmark;

public Address(){}

public Address(String houseNo, String city, String pincode, String landmark) {
    this.houseNo = houseNo;
    this.city = city;
    this.pincode = pincode;
    this.landmark = landmark;
}

public String getHouseNo() {
    return houseNo;
}

public void setHouseNo(String houseNo) {
    this.houseNo = houseNo;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getPincode() {
    return pincode;
}

public void setPincode(String pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}

public String getLandmark() {
    return landmark;
}

public void setLandmark(String landmark) {
    this.landmark = landmark;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Address{" +
            "houseNo='" + houseNo + '\'' +
            ", city='" + city + '\'' +
            ", pincode='" + pincode + '\'' +
            ", landmark='" + landmark + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

**StudentRepository.java**

```
import com.Spring.Data.Student;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
   List<Student> findByPinCode(String pincode);
   List<Student> findByName(String lastName);
}
```

**Application.java**

```
package com.Spring.DataJPA;

import com.Spring.Data.Address;
import com.Spring.Data.Student;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DataJpaApplication {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataJpaApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(DataJpaApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner runner(StudentRepository repository){
    return (args) -> {
        Address address0 = new Address(
                "3-14-5","Tuni","533401","MR Peta"
        );
        Student student0 = new Student(
                "Anjaneya",
                "varma",
                24,
                address0
        );
        Address address1 = new Address(
                "3-14-5","Tuni","533402","MR Peta"
        );
        Student student1 = new Student(
                "Tirupathi",
                "Raju",
                50,
                address1
        );
        repository.save(student0);
        repository.save(student1);

        log.info("Students found with findAll():");
        log.info("-------------------------------");
        for(Student student: repository.findAll()){
            log.info(student.toString());
        }
        log.info("");
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Spring by default looks for Beans in the package (and subpackages) where your `@SpringBootApplication` is. But your Repository is not in the `com.Spring.DataJPA` package, but instead in `com.Spring.Data`

Comment: Benjamin M is right.  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68561130/280244 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This errors occurs because spring isn't reading the package that your enity is.Try to use on your SpringConfig :

```
 @EntityScan("your.base.package.*")
```